# How move divs up/down using CSS animation without a "blink" between directions?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to move these divs up and down based on clicks:

- Initial click moves them up
- Next Click moves them down (then repeat on next clicks)

Moving them up works well, but when i click to move them down, they flash invisible first and then move down. What am I doing wrong?

*JSFiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/9q0scpa0/

HTML:

```
<div class="page" id="page1" onclick="restart()">
    Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
    Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
    Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
    Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page2" onclick="restart()">
    Page 2
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

html
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page
{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes moveNext
{
  0% {
    transform: translate(0em,100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes movePrevious
{
  0% {
    transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    display: block;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(0em,0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,0%);
  }
}

#page1.leave
{
  z-index: 0;
  animation-name: moveNext;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page2.enter
{
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: moveNext;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page1.enter
{
  z-index: 0;
  animation-name: movePrevious;
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page2.leave
{
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: movePrevious;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var isMoveNext = true;
var page1 = document.getElementById( "page1" );
var page2 = document.getElementById( "page2" );

window.restart = function()
{
  //Moving next
  if ( isMoveNext )
  {
    page1.className = "page leave";
    page2.className = "page enter";
    isMoveNext = false;
  }

  else
  {
    page1.className = "page enter";
    page2.className = "page leave";
    isMoveNext = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: without looking at all the details, setting `animation-fill-mode: backwards;` in #page2.leave seemed to solve the flicker (https://jsfiddle.net/9q0scpa0/2/ ) Haven't tested if it actually does what's expected though

Comment: @Me.Name yes, it think it works ok . And seems to me the cleanest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more transition `translate(0em,-100%)` in `#page2.leave` to remove the blink

```js
var isMoveNext = true;
var page1 = document.getElementById( "page1" );
var page2 = document.getElementById( "page2" );

window.restart = function()
{
 //Moving next
  if ( isMoveNext )
  {
  page1.className = "page leave";
    page2.className = "page enter";
    isMoveNext = false;
  }
  
  else
  {
   page1.className = "page enter";
    page2.className = "page leave";
    isMoveNext = true;
  }
}
```

```css
*
{
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

html
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page
{
  position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: red;
}

@keyframes moveNext
{
  0% {
  transform: translate(0em,100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em,0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0em,0%);
 }
 
 100% {
  transform: translate(0em,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
 }
}

@keyframes movePrevious
{
  0% {
  transform: translate(0em,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    display: block;
 }
 
 100% {
  transform: translate(0em,0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em,0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0em,0%);
 }
}

#page1.leave
{
  z-index: 0;
  animation-name: moveNext;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page2.enter
{
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: moveNext;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page1.enter
{
  z-index: 0;
  animation-name: movePrevious;
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#page2.leave
{
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: movePrevious;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      transform: translate(0em,-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
        -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="page1" onclick="restart()">
Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>Page 1<br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page2" onclick="restart()">
Page 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You achieve your animation by using only `transition` you don't need to use **keyframes**

this how css look like :

```
*
{
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

html
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    transition:all linear 800ms;
}

#page2{

    background-color: blue;
}

#page1.leave,#page2.enter
{
    transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,-100%);
}



#page1.enter,#page2.leave
{
    transform: translate(0em,-0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em,-0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0em,-0%);
}
```

[**See demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9q0scpa0/3/)

Comment: nice , khshina :D